# Passing a string as a regex pattern to String.prototype.replace

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace

How to convert a string to a regex pattern that works with the string.replace prototype?

Expected solution:

```
var regex = "/(\w+)_(\w+)/i";
var pattern = new RegExp(regex);
console.log("some_name".replace(pattern, "$1-$2"));
// expected output: some-name
// output: some_name
```

## [Edit 1]

It appears to be that the regex pattern was part of the reason the code above would not work as expected, however, for some reason, passing the same pattern as a RegExp, as King Stone outlined, does.

Comment: Just as a heads up, `\w` also captures the `_` character.

Comment: It turns out the regex was confusing me, since it works as a RegExp but it doesn't work as a string converted to RegExp.

Comment: Use the `RegExp` constructor only when your regular expression is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pattern = /(\w+)_(\w+)/i;
// var pattern = new RegExp(regex);
console.log("some_name".replace(pattern, "$1-$2"));
```

**Output:**

> some-name

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you've changed ?

Comment: The problem with this is that the pattern is not actually being passed as a string but as a RegExp. The objective is to convert a string into an instance of RegExp and pass it to string.prototype.replace.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a regex to the constructor of RegExp. [See Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

As `\w` also matches an underscore, you can match a word character except the underscore using a negated character class `[^\W_]`

```
([^\W_]+)_([^\W_]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iGAQZa/1)

**Note** to double escape the backslashes for the RegExp constructor.

If the objective is to convert a string into an instance of RegExp and pass it to string.prototype.replace you might use:

```js
let str = "([^\\W_]+)_([^\\W_]+)";
let pattern = new RegExp(str);
console.log("some_name".replace(pattern, "$1-$2"));
```

Comment: @WaleedQidan It works because `\w+` will first match all the characters in the string `some_name`, then it will backtrack to match the `_` and then it will match the rest of the string with the second `\w+` You can prevent the backtracking to match a word character without the underscore using `[^\W_]`

Comment: thank you for your explanation. However, my question is why does the same regex pattern `"/(\w+)_(\w+)/i"` return the expected result (some-name) when passed as an instance of RegExp `var = /(\w+)_(\w+)/i`?

Comment: @WaleedQidan That is explained on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't Strings, so you need to remove the quotation marks out of the expression. The forward slashes at the beginning and the end (sometimes followed by i and g) are what determine the bounds of the expression:

```js
var regex = /(\w+)_(\w+)/i;
var pattern = new RegExp(regex);
console.log("some_name".replace(pattern, "$1-$2"));
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why does The fourth bird's regular expression work despite being enclosed within quotation marks?

Comment: @WaleedQidan probably because they omitted the forward slashes